# Message is only read by client after server closes the connection end in java

Tags: java, java-io, jpos

I have been trying to send ISO8583 messages created with the JPOS Library in Java.
What I have done is written a simple code of socket connection for sending message.
I'm able to send the message successfully but the problem is the server sends a response on time but the message is not read by my client socket.
It only reads the data after I close the connection forcefully (disconnect the socket manually) at server.

I need to send more than 100 messages over the same connection and receive responses for them. What can I do to make this work and let the client immediately read each message when the server sends it?

Here is my sample code for sending:

```
logISOMsg(isoMsg);
byte[]  send_PackedRequestData = isoMsg.pack();
BufferedOutputStream outStream=null;
BufferedReader receiveStream=null;

Socket connection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5874);
if (connection.isConnected()) {

    outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    outStream.write(send_PackedRequestData);
    outStream.flush();
}
```

and for reading:

```
if (connection.isConnected()) {
    receiveStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String isoMessage = receiveStream.readLine();

    ISOMsg isoMsg1 = new ISOMsg(); 
    isoMsg1.setPackager(packager);   

    byte[] bIsoMessage = new byte[isoMessage.length()];   
    for (int i = 0; i < bIsoMessage.length; i++) {
        bIsoMessage[i] = (byte) (int) isoMessage.charAt(i); 
    }                                
    isoMsg1.unpack(bIsoMessage); 

    System.out.println("MTI='"+isoMsg1.getMTI()+"'");     
    for (int i=1; i<=isoMsg1.getMaxField(); i++) {
        if (isoMsg1.hasField(i))
            System.out.println("DE : "+ i + " =  " + isoMsg1.getString(i) + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which buffer are you talking about

Comment: Server can send a message of variable length so how can client decide.

Comment: Since you can only flush a write buffer, that's the one I suggest you flush

Comment: Also the server is an EFT Switch

Comment: How does the client know the length of the message?  Do you tell it?  Do you have a terminator?

Comment: I have already added it ( outStream.flush();)

Comment: No the JPOS Library helps to create a bitmap.

Comment: based on the the Switch parses the message which i send

Comment: `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the points where you are testing it.

Answer (score 3):

The receiver needs to know somehow when to stop reading from the socket and return the message. This can basically be done in three ways: either you have a fixed length of messages, or you prefix each message with its length, or you have some terminator symbol that ends each message.

On the sender side, you just send the message without any further indication of how the receiver would know its length. As I do not know the ISO8583 standard, I cannot tell whether messages in this format may have one of the above features.

On the receiver side, however, you use `BufferedReader.readLine()`, which uses the third option and waits for a newline. Apparently your message is not terminated with a newline and thus the reader hangs infinitely waiting for a newline.

As the message is encoded in a byte array and not in a String, I strongly suspect that you should not use newline as a terminator symbol until it is guaranteed that this character will never occur in the message itself. You should instead check how one normally sends such messages, and how the receiver can know their length.

Furthermore, you are mixing Strings and byte arrays, which is a bug here. The sender sends a raw byte array. What happens on the receiver side is that the InputStreamReader internally converts the byte array into a String. This operation decodes bytes into characters using a charset such as UTF-8. You do not even specify which charset to use, thus the output can be pretty much arbitrary. Afterwards your code converts the String back into a byte array, but this code is wrong and does not guarantee to restore the original content (the resulting byte array may be different than the one the server sent).

Thus you should not use any Reader class on the receiver side, if you do not use a Writer class on the sender side. Instead use only Streams as you do while sending.